# How should I implement a binarySearch recursively for rectangles?

Tags: java, recursion

I am writing a binarySearch method recursively for rectangles. 
My rectangle class works fine
Here is it:

```
    public class Rectangle implements Comparable<Rectangle> {
    private int length;
    private int width;
        private int perimeter;


    public Rectangle(int l, int w){
        this.length = l;
        this.width = w;
    } 

    public  int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public  int getWidth(){
        return width;
    }

        public void setLength(int l){
            length= l;
        }
        public void setWidth(int w){
            width = w;
        }

    public int getPerimeter(){
               perimeter = 2*(length+width);

               return perimeter;
    }




        @Override
    public int compareTo(Rectangle other){
               return Double.compare(this.getPerimeter(), other.getPerimeter());
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "Rectangle: "+ width +" by "+ length ;
        }
}
```

but the problem is with my binarySearch method
in the main method i couldn't print out the actual rectangle. I don't know if it is the method itself that's wrong or if it is the way I write it in the print?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Problem2{

    public static <AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>>       
     int binarySearch(AnyType[] a, AnyType x){
        return binarySearch(a, x, 0, a.length-1);
     }

    public static <AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>> int binarySearch
      (AnyType[] a, AnyType x, int start, int stop){
        if(start < stop)
            {
                int mid = (stop + start) / 2;
                if(x.compareTo(a[mid]) == -1)
                    return binarySearch(a, x, start, mid);
                else if(x.compareTo(a[mid]) == 1)
                    return binarySearch(a, x, mid+1, stop);
                else
                    return mid;
            }
        return -1;
    }

      public static void main(String []args){

            Rectangle[] arr = { new Rectangle(2,6), new Rectangle(4,7), new Rectangle(3,9),
                                new Rectangle(1,2), new Rectangle(2,4), new Rectangle(7,7)}; 


            for(Rectangle rec: arr){
            System.out.println("the list is " + rec);
            }

          System.out.println(binarySearch(arr,arr[5]));

      }
}
```

So basically if you run this the above part works fine. The last printout doesnt give me rectangles. It prints out numbers. Like if it is arr[1]then it prints 1, but if it is 5 then it gives -1.

Answer (score 0):

Your `binarySearch` method returns the *index* in the array where your rectangle was found, not the rectangle itself.

You want something like this:

```
int index = binarySearch(arr,arr[5]);
if (index != -1)
    System.out.println(arr[index]);
else
    System.out.println("Rectangle not found");
```

Comment: yes i realized! so should the print statement be sth like this?  System.out.println(binarySearch(arr, Rectangle(4,7)); I am confused about the Anytype x part